# Prevent from being added ".ck-reset" classes in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

By default, CK-Editor adds the resetting CSS classes like ".ck-reset":

```css
.ck.ck-reset, .ck.ck-reset_all, .ck.ck-reset_all * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

What if I don't wish these classes? Which option is corresponding to disabling of CSS resetting classes?

Comment: What is your use-case for this? Do you want to add your own classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can try to solve this (copied from the GH issue below):

1. A custom PostCSS plugin that replaces all .ck-reset statements with :not(.some-component) .ck-reset to disable CKEditor 5 reset in your component.
2. Package.json level script that replaces the _reset.css files with your own css file with the not(.some-component)
3. Wait for the issue to be resolved, per - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/3424